# Boolean Perceptron for the NOT Function

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, boolean-logic, perceptron

I'm trying to implement a simple perceptron for the basic boolean expression. But I was not able correctly traine the NOT perceptron.

I was successfully able to traine the **AND** and **OR** perceptron to return the correct values for the given input set. But when I try to traine the **NOT**.

That is how I'm doing it:

The **AND** and **OR** perceptron have two inputs, two weights and One **Bias**(with fixed **1** to the bias input).

All perceptron starts with **0** on all **weights**.
Then I generate random values (between 0 and 1) to traine the perceptrons, and keep it on a loop until I get 10 correctly guesses.

They have a learning rate of **0.1**

**This is the training process:**

To guess the value:
For each input I multiply the input for the weight, and sum all values, including the bias.

```
sum = (weight1 * input1) + (weight2 * input2) + (biasWeight * biasInput)--Bias input is fixed to 1
return = if (sum > 0) then 1 else 0
```

To traine the perceptron:
I get the guess from the perceptron

```
val = and.guess(1,0) --This will return 0 or 1
error = answer - val
```

For each input I execute this calculation

```
weight = weight + (input * error * rate)
```

Then I do the same for the bias

```
biasWeight = biasWeight + (input * error * rate)--Bias input is fixed to 1
```

With this process, I can successfully traine the **AND** and **OR** perceptron.

The only difference between the **AND**/**OR** and the **NOT** perceptron is the number of **Inputs** (only 1 for the **NOT**)

But the NOT perceptron just keep growing the weight by the number in the learning rate.

Some times, depending on the training order of the **NOT** Perceptron it get the correctly values when it hit **0.5**.

There is the code (html, javascript) when I got home to post the code. I actually found the bug. the **CALC** function that should return **weight * input** was returning **weight + input**, and it actually worked for the **AND** and **OR** training.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Show(text) {
            if (!text) {
                text = '';
            }

            document.writeln(text + '<br />');
        }

        //return random value from 0 ~ 1
        function getRandom() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        };

        function PerceptronData(input, weight) {
            this.input = input;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
        PerceptronData.prototype.calc = function () {
            var result = this.input + this.weight;
            return result;
        };
        PerceptronData.prototype.adjust = function (error, rate) {
            this.weight += (this.input * error * rate);
        };
        PerceptronData.prototype.print = function () {
            return '(' + this.input + ', ' + this.weight + ')';
        }

        function Perceptron(n) {
            this.data = [];//Data array [input, weight]
            this.bias = new PerceptronData(1, 0);
            this.rate = 0.1;//learning rate

            //initial data
            for (var index = 0; index < n; index++) {
                this.data.push(new PerceptronData(0, 0));
            }
        }
        //called from "guess" function in the final perceptron
        Perceptron.prototype.process = function (inputs) {
            var data = this.data;

            if (inputs.length != data.length) {
                throw "The number os inputs [" + inputs.length + "] doesn't match with the start value [" + data.length + "] of the Perceptron.";
            }

            var dataSum = 0;
            for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                data[index].input = parseInt(inputs[index]);
                dataSum += data[index].calc();
            }

            dataSum += this.bias.calc();

            return dataSum;
        };
        //twick the weight for every data
        Perceptron.prototype.adjust = function (value, answer) {
            var data = this.data;
            var error = answer - value;

            for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                data[index].adjust(error, this.rate);
            }

            this.bias.adjust(error, this.rate);
        };
        Perceptron.prototype.print = function () {
            var data = this.data;
            var result = '';
            for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                result += 'data[' + index + ']' + data[index].print() + ' > ';
            }

            return result + 'bias' + this.bias.print();
        };

        function NotPerceptron() {
            Perceptron.call(this, 1);
        }
        NotPerceptron.prototype = Object.create(Perceptron.prototype);
        NotPerceptron.prototype.guess = function (value) {
            var data = this.process([value]);

            //activation function
            return ((data > 0) ? 1 : 0);
        };
        NotPerceptron.prototype.train = function (value, answer) {
            var result = this.guess([value]);
            this.adjust(result, answer);
        };

        function AndPerceptron() {
            Perceptron.call(this, 2);
        }
        AndPerceptron.prototype = Object.create(Perceptron.prototype);
        AndPerceptron.prototype.guess = function (valueA, valueB) {
            var data = this.process([valueA, valueB]);

            //activation function
            return ((data > 0) ? 1 : 0);
        };
        AndPerceptron.prototype.train = function (valueA, valueB, answer) {
            var result = this.guess(valueA, valueB);

            this.adjust(result, answer);
        };

        function OrPerceptron() {
            Perceptron.call(this, 2);
        }
        OrPerceptron.prototype = Object.create(Perceptron.prototype);
        OrPerceptron.prototype.guess = function (valueA, valueB) {
            var data = this.process([valueA, valueB]);

            //activation function
            return ((data > 0) ? 1 : 0);
        };
        OrPerceptron.prototype.train = function (valueA, valueB, answer) {
            var result = this.guess(valueA, valueB);

            this.adjust(result, answer);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Show('Training AND...');
        Show();
        var and = new AndPerceptron();

        var count = 0;
        var total = 0;
        var max = 100;

        while (count < 10 && total < max) {
            total++;
            var a = getRandom();
            var b = getRandom();
            var answer = ((a === 1 && b === 1) ? 1 : 0);

            and.train(a, b, answer);

            a = getRandom();
            b = getRandom();
            answer = ((a === 1 && b === 1) ? 1 : 0);

            var guess = and.guess(a, b);

            if (guess === answer) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }

            Show(' > AND(' + a + ', ' + b + ') = ' + guess + ' > [' + and.print() + ']');

            if (count == 10) {
                //final test
                if (and.guess(0, 0) == 1) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (and.guess(0, 1) == 1) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (and.guess(1, 0) == 1) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (and.guess(1, 1) == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        Show();

        if (total >= max) {
            Show('AND training failed...');
        } else {
            Show('AND trained with [' + total + '] interactions. [' + and.print() + ']');
        }

        Show();
        Show('AND(0, 0) = ' + and.guess(0, 0));
        Show('AND(0, 1) = ' + and.guess(0, 1));
        Show('AND(1, 0) = ' + and.guess(1, 0));
        Show('AND(1, 1) = ' + and.guess(1, 1));

        Show();
        Show('Training OR...');
        Show();
        var or = new OrPerceptron();

        count = 0;
        total = 0;
        max = 100;

        while (count < 10 && total < max) {
            total++;
            var a = getRandom();
            var b = getRandom();
            var answer = ((a === 1 || b === 1) ? 1 : 0);

            or.train(a, b, answer);

            a = getRandom();
            b = getRandom();
            answer = ((a === 1 || b === 1) ? 1 : 0);

            var guess = or.guess(a, b);

            if (guess === answer) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }

            Show(' > OR(' + a + ', ' + b + ') = ' + guess + ' > [' + or.print() + ']');

            if (count == 10) {
                //final test
                if (or.guess(0, 0) == 1) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (or.guess(0, 1) == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (or.guess(1, 0) == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (or.guess(1, 1) == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        Show();

        if (total >= max) {
            Show('OR training failed...');
        } else {
            Show('OR trained with [' + total + '] interactions. [' + or.print() + ']');
        }

        Show();
        Show('OR(0, 0) = ' + or.guess(0, 0));
        Show('OR(0, 1) = ' + or.guess(0, 1));
        Show('OR(1, 0) = ' + or.guess(1, 0));
        Show('OR(1, 1) = ' + or.guess(1, 1));

        Show();
        Show('Training NOT...');
        Show();
        var not = new NotPerceptron();
        not.rate = 0.1;

        count = 0;
        total = 0;
        max = 100;

        while (count < 10 && total < max) {
            total++;
            var test = getRandom();
            var answer = ((test === 1) ? 0 : 1);

            not.train(test, answer);

            test = getRandom();
            answer = ((test === 1) ? 0 : 1);

            var guess = not.guess(test);

            if (guess === answer) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }

            Show(' > NOT(' + test + ') = ' + guess + ' > [' + not.print() + ']');

            if (count == 10) {
                //final test
                if (not.guess(0) == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (not.guess(1) == 1) {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        Show();

        if (total >= max) {
            Show('NOT training failed...');
        } else {
            Show('NOT trained with [' + total + '] interactions. [' + not.print() + ']');
        }

        Show();
        Show('NOT(1) = ' + not.guess(1));
        Show('NOT(0) = ' + not.guess(0));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output:

```
Training AND...

> AND(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> AND(1, 1) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0) > bias(1, 0)]
> AND(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0) > bias(1, 0)]
> AND(1, 1) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0) > bias(1, 0)]
> AND(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0) > bias(1, 0)]
> AND(0, 1) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0) > bias(1, 0)]
> AND(0, 1) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0) > data[1](1, 0) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(0, 1) = 1 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> AND(0, 1) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 1) = 0 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 1) = 0 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 0) = 0 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 1) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.2) > data[1](1, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> AND(0, 0) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 0) = 0 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 0) = 0 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 0) = 0 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 0) = 0 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(0, 0) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(1, 0) = 0 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> AND(0, 0) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]

AND trained with [21] interactions. [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0.1) > bias(1, -0.1)]

AND(0, 0) = 0
AND(0, 1) = 0
AND(1, 0) = 0
AND(1, 1) = 1

Training OR...

> OR(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> OR(0, 1) = 1 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0.1) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> OR(0, 1) = 1 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0.1) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> OR(0, 0) = 1 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> OR(0, 0) = 1 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> OR(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> OR(0, 1) = 1 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0.1) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> OR(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> OR(0, 0) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> OR(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> OR(0, 0) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> OR(0, 0) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> OR(1, 1) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> OR(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> OR(1, 0) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](0, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]

OR trained with [15] interactions. [data[0](1, 0.1) > data[1](1, 0.1) > bias(1, 0)]

OR(0, 0) = 0
OR(0, 1) = 1
OR(1, 0) = 1
OR(1, 1) = 1

Training NOT...

> NOT(0) = 0 > [data[0](0, 0) > bias(1, 0)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, 0) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, 0) > bias(1, 0.1)]
> NOT(0) = 0 > [data[0](0, -0.1) > bias(1, 0)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.2) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.2) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -0.2) > bias(1, -0.1)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -0.30000000000000004) > bias(1, -0.2)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.30000000000000004) > bias(1, -0.2)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -0.30000000000000004) > bias(1, -0.2)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.4) > bias(1, -0.30000000000000004)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.5) > bias(1, -0.4)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.5) > bias(1, -0.4)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.6) > bias(1, -0.5)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.6) > bias(1, -0.5)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.7) > bias(1, -0.6)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.7999999999999999) > bias(1, -0.7)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -0.8999999999999999) > bias(1, -0.7999999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -0.8999999999999999) > bias(1, -0.7999999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -0.9999999999999999) > bias(1, -0.8999999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -0.9999999999999999) > bias(1, -0.8999999999999999)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -0.9999999999999999) > bias(1, -0.8999999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -0.9999999999999999) > bias(1, -0.8999999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.0999999999999999) > bias(1, -0.9999999999999999)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.2) > bias(1, -1.0999999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.2) > bias(1, -1.0999999999999999)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.2) > bias(1, -1.0999999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.2) > bias(1, -1.0999999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.2) > bias(1, -1.0999999999999999)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.2) > bias(1, -1.0999999999999999)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.3) > bias(1, -1.2)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.4000000000000001) > bias(1, -1.3)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.5000000000000002) > bias(1, -1.4000000000000001)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.6000000000000003) > bias(1, -1.5000000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.6000000000000003) > bias(1, -1.5000000000000002)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.6000000000000003) > bias(1, -1.5000000000000002)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.7000000000000004) > bias(1, -1.6000000000000003)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -1.8000000000000005) > bias(1, -1.7000000000000004)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.9000000000000006) > bias(1, -1.8000000000000005)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.9000000000000006) > bias(1, -1.8000000000000005)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.9000000000000006) > bias(1, -1.8000000000000005)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -1.9000000000000006) > bias(1, -1.8000000000000005)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -2.0000000000000004) > bias(1, -1.9000000000000006)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -2.1000000000000005) > bias(1, -2.0000000000000004)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -2.2000000000000006) > bias(1, -2.1000000000000005)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -2.3000000000000007) > bias(1, -2.2000000000000006)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -2.3000000000000007) > bias(1, -2.2000000000000006)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -2.400000000000001) > bias(1, -2.3000000000000007)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -2.500000000000001) > bias(1, -2.400000000000001)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -2.600000000000001) > bias(1, -2.500000000000001)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -2.700000000000001) > bias(1, -2.600000000000001)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -2.800000000000001) > bias(1, -2.700000000000001)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -2.9000000000000012) > bias(1, -2.800000000000001)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.0000000000000013) > bias(1, -2.9000000000000012)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.0000000000000013) > bias(1, -2.9000000000000012)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.0000000000000013) > bias(1, -2.9000000000000012)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -3.1000000000000014) > bias(1, -3.0000000000000013)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -3.1000000000000014) > bias(1, -3.0000000000000013)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.2000000000000015) > bias(1, -3.1000000000000014)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -3.3000000000000016) > bias(1, -3.2000000000000015)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.4000000000000017) > bias(1, -3.3000000000000016)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -3.5000000000000018) > bias(1, -3.4000000000000017)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -3.600000000000002) > bias(1, -3.5000000000000018)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.700000000000002) > bias(1, -3.600000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.700000000000002) > bias(1, -3.600000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.800000000000002) > bias(1, -3.700000000000002)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -3.800000000000002) > bias(1, -3.700000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -3.900000000000002) > bias(1, -3.800000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.000000000000002) > bias(1, -3.900000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.000000000000002) > bias(1, -3.900000000000002)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.000000000000002) > bias(1, -3.900000000000002)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.000000000000002) > bias(1, -3.900000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.100000000000001) > bias(1, -4.000000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.100000000000001) > bias(1, -4.000000000000002)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.200000000000001) > bias(1, -4.100000000000001)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.300000000000001) > bias(1, -4.200000000000001)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.300000000000001) > bias(1, -4.200000000000001)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.4) > bias(1, -4.300000000000001)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.5) > bias(1, -4.4)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.5) > bias(1, -4.4)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.5) > bias(1, -4.4)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.6) > bias(1, -4.5)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.699999999999999) > bias(1, -4.6)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.799999999999999) > bias(1, -4.699999999999999)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -4.799999999999999) > bias(1, -4.699999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.899999999999999) > bias(1, -4.799999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -4.999999999999998) > bias(1, -4.899999999999999)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.099999999999998) > bias(1, -4.999999999999998)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.1999999999999975) > bias(1, -5.099999999999998)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.299999999999997) > bias(1, -5.1999999999999975)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.299999999999997) > bias(1, -5.1999999999999975)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.299999999999997) > bias(1, -5.1999999999999975)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -5.299999999999997) > bias(1, -5.1999999999999975)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.299999999999997) > bias(1, -5.1999999999999975)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.299999999999997) > bias(1, -5.1999999999999975)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.399999999999997) > bias(1, -5.299999999999997)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.4999999999999964) > bias(1, -5.399999999999997)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -5.599999999999996) > bias(1, -5.4999999999999964)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.699999999999996) > bias(1, -5.599999999999996)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -5.799999999999995) > bias(1, -5.699999999999996)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.899999999999995) > bias(1, -5.799999999999995)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -5.999999999999995) > bias(1, -5.899999999999995)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -6.099999999999994) > bias(1, -5.999999999999995)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -6.199999999999994) > bias(1, -6.099999999999994)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -6.199999999999994) > bias(1, -6.099999999999994)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -6.199999999999994) > bias(1, -6.099999999999994)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -6.199999999999994) > bias(1, -6.099999999999994)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -6.199999999999994) > bias(1, -6.099999999999994)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -6.199999999999994) > bias(1, -6.099999999999994)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -6.199999999999994) > bias(1, -6.099999999999994)]
> NOT(1) = 1 > [data[0](1, -6.299999999999994) > bias(1, -6.199999999999994)]
> NOT(0) = 1 > [data[0](0, -6.399999999999993) > bias(1, -6.299999999999994)]
```

Comment: please add the code as well.

Comment: When I got home to edit the question and post the code, I actually found the bug. But thanks any way. I have updated the question with all code.

Comment: So what's the problem? Now it works well. Post your answer and accept it. I think your question is quite illuminative and shouldn't be closed as "caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Comment: ok, I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Stanislav Kralin sugestion, I have updated the question again so it shows up the problem. And here is the solution.

The problem was with the **CALC** function that should multiply the value of the input for the weight. But I was adding it.

Unfortunately i was so focuses looking about if I should use a **sigmoid** function or other function, looking about the learning rate and linear and non linear functions, that I didn't saw this mistake.

And the fact that works well with the **AND** and **OR** perceptron really toke me to the wrong direction.

```
PerceptronData.prototype.calc = function () {
    //var result = this.input + this.weight;//This was wrong... :(
    var result = this.input * this.weight;
    return result;
};
```